# При добавлении label в код checkbox по какой-то причине перестает работать

Tags: html, css, html5, checkbox

```css
.burger:checked+div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="inp" class="burger" checked="checked">
  <label for="inp">Label</label>
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

При добавлении label в код checkbox по какой-то причине перестает работать, как можно это исправить, или переписать но правильно.
Если же убрать тег label то все начинает работать как положено.

PS: код написан в очень тестовом варианте, код может быть слабо читаемым, извините.
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: .burger:checked ~ div или .burger:checked + label + div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Селектор `.burger:checked+div` обозначает выбрать `div`, который находится на том же уровне вложенности, что и `.burger:checked`, и следует **непосредственно** за ним. Но у вас непосредственно за чекбоксом следует элемент `label`. Соответственно селектор не выбирает элементов.

Вам же нужно указать комбинатор `~`, который  выберет все элементы на том же уровне вложенности

```css
.burger:checked~div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="inp" class="burger" checked="checked">
  <label for="inp">Label</label>
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов, перенести все внутрь `label`

```css
.checkbox {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.checkbox__control:checked~.checkbox__text {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" class="checkbox__control" checked>
    <span class="checkbox__label">Label</span>
    <span class="checkbox__text">Hello</span>    
  </label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" class="checkbox__control" checked>
    <span class="checkbox__label">Label 2</span>
    <span class="checkbox__text">Hello 2</span>    
  </label>
```